# Disassemble a file and get the bytes from the text section

Tags: linux, disassembly, objdump

I am trying to disassemble a file on Ubuntu and extract only the text section.
To do this I am using `objdump -d executable_file > dump`. This gives me nice human-readable output.

However, I am looking for the binary bytes (which are displayed in the second column of the output):

```
MEM_ADDRESS <.text>:
 MEM_ADDRESS:   XX XX                   HUMAN_READABLE_DISASM
 MEM_ADDRESS:   XX XX XX XX             HUMAN_READABLE_DISASM
```

What I want to extract is the `XX` as a single stream of bytes, just as in the original binary.

Is it possible to do this without parsing the output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `objcopy` utility to extract a section, e.g.

```
objcopy --output-target=binary --only-section=.text input.elf output.bin
```